# Can't Edit Registry though admin

Tags: windows-7

I can't edit my registry though I am logged in as the administrator. 'Registry editing has been disabled by your administrator'

Comment: Rollo: Is this Pro or Home windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

**If this computer is part of a network domain**, the network administrator may have group policies in place to prevent you from editing your registry.

**If this is a standalone computer**, this could be caused by malware or a virus. You should probably run a program like [Malware Bytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org) or [SpyBot S&D](http://www.safer-networking.org/index2.html) to make sure the system is clean of malware, spyware, or adware. Run a complete virus scan on your system. A free online scan at [eSet](http://www.eset.com/us/online-scanner/) just to make sure its clean might be a good idea.

Once you know it's clean:

`Click Start -> Run -> type gpedit.msc -> press enter -> User Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Prevent access to registry editing tools -> Right Click Properties -> Set it to Not Configured`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running it as administrator? Even though you are logged in with an administrator account, I'm pretty sure you still have to Run as Administrator on Regedit.

Comment: No, I run regedit from a run box (Win+R) all the time and its not elevated doing it this way, no problems making changes either.